# If statement based on Boolean Value

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, constructor, boolean

I am trying to set my true and false return from my method in another class as the conditional to my if statement. We are creating a password generator. Are set password is changit. If the user enters changeit as the original password then the new password the user would like to enter will become the password. if not then the users password will stay the same as the original password. I created a method that returned a true or false if the oldPassword is equal to password. else it will return false. I need this return to go back in my main file and to be used in an if statement. Please help me! i am posting my if statements (which are in a separate file called Main.java) and my boolean method (which are in a separate file called Password.java) all my code works except for my if statements

```
//My method in anotherfile called Password.java

public boolean checkPassword(String oldPassword) {

    if (password.equals(oldPassword)) {
        System.out.println("True");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("False");
        return false;
    }
}

//my constructor 

passwordObject.checkPassword(oldPassword);

//my if statement for main.java to show if i was able to successfully change my password.
if (checkPassword == true) {
    System.out.println("Your password change was successful");
} else {
    System.out.println("Your password change was unsucessesful");
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: This is pretty garbled. I don't understand the question and the code is confusing to read -- it seems to be separate segments of code but the way it's formatted makes it appear as on contiguous segment. Please fix your question to clarify what the actual problem is in addition to fixing your code.

Comment: I need to use the return value from my boolean method in my true and false statement. Sorry I'm really struggling with this and its due tomorrow

Comment: not sure what you question is but your logic seems inverted... from your code... 
if password == oldPassword  it return true and then print password sucessfully changed!!!

in my opinion if your password == oldPassword then your password is not changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In place of `if (checkPassword == true)` you need:

```
if(passwordObject.checkPassword(oldPassword)){
    //more code

}
```

`checkPassword` as a boolean variable isn't accessible from your main class, even if it was being set in your `Password` class (and it's not).

When you're calling `passwordObject.checkPassword(oldPassword);` what you're doing is telling that method to run in `passwordObject`'s class, and it does. But the result of that method (true/false) isn't being saved -- it's meant to be *returned* to whatever class is invoking the method (in this case, the `main` method).

To break down the above solution, it's the same as doing this:

```
boolean passwordCheckResult = passwordObject.checkPassword(oldPassword);
//above line stores whatever checkPassword returns, into passwordCheckResult

if(passwordCheckResult == true){
    //more code
}
```

Comment: that did not work. and it is not in the main class. it is in a separate class. i just put them by each other

Comment: @Angela You'll have to elaborate then. If `checkPassword` is in a separate class (whichever class `passwordObject` belongs to), this should work fine.

Comment: no this does not work because it makes the program run through check password twice making the return false. Should i show you both my files?

Comment: Nvm that worked when i set it equal to passwordCheckResult. Thank you so much!!